# Adding txt file lines into seperated textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, line, each, notepad

for example i have an app with 3 text-boxes (not multi line) and a notepad txt file with 3 lines. when i click a button, the app must fill each line with a line of textbox for example i have a .txt file like this :

```
zzzzzzzzzzz  
yyyyyyyyyy  
nnnnnnnnn
```

and i want a `textbox1` show `"zzzzzzzzzzz"` , `textbox2` show `"yyyyyyyyy"` , and `textbox3` show `"nnnnnnnn"`.
 so how can i do this in C# ?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, we won't do all the work for you.

Comment: Read the text file into an array. Stick each element of the array into a different text box. Job done. I assume it was only the overview that you had problems with and that you are fine of the coding of each part of this, right? ;-)

Comment: So you want to dynamically create as many text boxes as the text file has lines? So if the text file has 1,000 lines, then you want 1,000 text boxes on your UI?

Comment: thats the problem i dont know where to start. i know how to add a whole text file but how to read and add line by line i dont know

Comment: @KarlAnderson yes thats it

Comment: @chris can you open it a bit ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Explanation:**
you can use built-in method `ReadAllLines()` of `File` class to read the all lines from your file.

Example: `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);`

`ReadAllLines()` return the String Array of all lines from file ,so you can store them for later use.

Example : `String [] allLines= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);`

Now take each line from StringArray and assign it to TextBox Control.

Example: `textBox1.Text = allLines[0];`

**Code :**

```
    String [] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    if(allLines.Length > 0)
    textBox1.Text = allLines[0];

    if(allLines.Length > 1)
    textBox2.Text = allLines[1];

    if(allLines.Length > 2)
    textBox3.Text = allLines[2];
```

Comment: Throws an exception if the file has less than 3 lines.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : now i have modified code so that it will take care if there are no/enough lines.

Comment: @Sudhakar: You could also use `ElementAtOrDefault` which assigns null if the index is out of range. `ElementAt...` uses also the array indexer behind the scenes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you sir, i don't know this before.

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("YourPath");
textbox1.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
textbox2.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
textbox3.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```